# How to insert a piece of text in a new buffer?

Tags: buffers

I have the following code:

````lisp
  (defconst cljs-test-report-buffer "*cljs-test-report*"
    "Buffer name in which to display test reports.")

  (defun cider-test-show-report ()
    "Show the test report buffer, if one exists."
    (interactive)
    (if-let* ((report-buffer (get-buffer cljs-test-report-buffer)))
        (switch-to-buffer report-buffer)
      (message "No test report buffer")))

  (defun run-cljs-test-in-ns ()
    (interactive)
    (cider-interactive-eval "(cljs.test/run-tests)")) 
;; want to show this result in the ```cljs-test-report-buffer```
````

And I want to show the result of the `run-cljs-test-in-ns` function in a new buffer, that is cleared every time this function is run. How can I do that?

Comment: You should specify in your question that you want to interact with cider, not just inserting a string/text in a buffer. I know nothing about `cider-interactive-eval`, or cider itself so I don't know what you expect. `find-file`, `insert` and `revert-buffer` will be a vanilla approach that will fit the question subject although I suspect it'll fall short, and comint maybe a long shot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this, in place of just `(run-cljs-test-in-ns)`:

```lisp
(pp-display-expression (run-cljs-test-in-ns) cljs-test-report-buffer)
```

That assumes that whatever function `run-cljs-test-in-ns` returns is what you want to show, and the value of `cljs-test-report-buffer` is the buffer or name of the buffer where you want to show it.